# Oracle SCD type 1

Tags: oracle

My understanding of SCD1 is if there is any change to the record the existing record is overwritten with the latest timestamp. Will the existing record be overwritten even if there is no change and will the timestamp be updated?

Comment: What ETL tool are you using? how is your update (or merge) coded by the tool? Your question lacks the information required for an answer

Comment: I am using Informatica and the code reads a flat file, right now it is coded in such a way that any incoming record replaces the existing record even if there is no change in any of the columns.

Comment: Yes, by default Informatica will process every row and do the update if it finds a match. Now, you can either look at ways to skip those updates (https://community.informatica.com/thread/41272 for example), or if your audit columns are populated by triggers you could only update the timestamp if a change has occurred.